# Only fade part of a background to white with CSS style sheet

Tags: css, image, background, stylesheet, linear-gradients

I'm trying to use this code in a CSS stylesheet:

```
.layered-image {
   background: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, white 40% ),
       url("http://www.azlro.org/chad/images/IMG_3699-1920x1080.JPG");
}
```

...to fade the background image from the image itself to white from left to right. However, I want some of image (500 pixels) to not fade at all and then start fading from there. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean, having the same effect but starting at 500px and fading to white from there, [like in this example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yocqryte/3/)? If so, you just need to place `500px` next to where your `transparent` colour is declared in your gradient.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to have the image fade to solid white within 200 pixels or whatever possible.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using the `::before` selector.
The ::before selector inserts something before the content of each selected element(s), in your case, the linear-gradient 'layer'.

I'm not totally sure this is what you are after, but hopefully this will guide you to a solution for your project.  You will have to play around with the opacity, width and possibly other factors to get it exactly how you want.

As the above commenter suggested, you can add values to each color inside your linear gradient to determine the amount that you want to persist, such as:

linear-gradient(to right, transparent **500px**, white);

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.layered-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Starsinthesky.jpg') center center   no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
  
.layered-image:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white);
   opacity: 2.5; 
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="layered-image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use opacity:

```
.layered-image {
     opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: When adding that above the background line it fades the image out more. Did I add it to the wrong place?

Comment: change the opacity value if you want white color

Answer (score 0):

Simply adjust the gradient:

```css
.layered-image {
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient( to right, transparent 0,transparent 200px /*edit this value*/ ,white 60%), 
  
  url("https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/") center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="layered-image">
</div>
```